# Implement 2-factor authentication with digital certificate

Tags: authentication, digital-signature, hardware-token

How can I implement digital certificate to do 2 factor authentication to a web application?

I have a web application under Apache server.
I want the application to require a digital certificate once trying to connect to it.
The certificate should be held on a token USB.
I have already received a server certificate from a certificate authority.

Comment: Welcome to Information Security. It seems that your does not provide enough details. In the current form it is likely to be closed. Please expand on your question. If you need more help, please see [help center](https://security.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Do you want to know how to activate client authentication on the server side or on the client side? Which OS and software are you using?